# What function should I use for logging in to receive(parse),validate and locally store some variables, with JQuery & JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is the code that currently I have, it works to the extent that it finds data.success and launches the next page when the correct value is returned, what I am having trouble with is parsing some additional data and passing to local storage so I use it on the next page, e.g user id, user name etc

```
$.post(postTo,{email:value1 , password:value2, tag:tagvar} , 

            function(data) {

                //$('#output').html('inside');

                if(data.success == '1') {

                  $.mobile.changePage( "home.html", { transition: "flip"} );


                } else {

                    $('#output').html('Could not connect please try again');

                }

            },'json');

       return false;
    });

});
```

Here  is the JSON returned from the request...

```
{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"4fc3562b9a8369.38575999","user":{"name":"test","email":"test@test.ie","created_at":"2012-05-28 11:40:43","updated_at":null,"ac":"8","user_type":"1"}}
```

I really am unsure of how to parse properly and also how to use local storage.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see that data parsed, you can use this nifty online parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/

From that point, you should be able to access and save whatever you need to (for example *data.user.name*).

As for saving data into local storage, check out [W3C manual](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) on that subject. Example:

```
...

if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
  localStorage.username = data.user.name;
}

...
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I was using the wrong syntax for local storage for some reason.